# How do I get the Signing Key ID from my GitHub account for TortoiseGit

Tags: windows, git, github, ssh, open-source

Im trying to contribute to a project, I forked the project but I cannot push to my fork

In TortoiseGit under credentials I can input Username, Email, and Signing Key ID

How do I get this signing key ID from github?

Google search on this subject did not come up with easy results that did not involve generating ssh keys in linux. Do I need to create an SSH key, or can I do it with my username? If I need ssh key, can I generate key through github? I don't have a .ssh directory on a windows machine

Comment: Check out these two links: 1) https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Signing-key-with-TortoiseGit-and-GitHub/td-p/10184 2) https://dev.to/c33s/sign-your-git-commits-with-tortoise-git-on-windows-3mlf.  The idea is: 1) You generate a keypair, 2) You export your public key and register it with your GitHub account, 3) You register it in your local Git configuration as "key id".  Subsequent commits will be signed with that key.